# Taylor expansion of characteristic function in probability theory

Tags: probability-theory

In probability theory, what is the Taylor expansion of characteristic function?

I know this is a basic question but I couldn't find a full answer.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Taylor expansions can exist functions on the real line. It's a general term from Calculus. In probability theory, the characteristic function of a random real variable is a function on the real line. Sometimes, it will have a useful Taylor series, which either converges to your function in some region or converges on the entire real line. For example, the bell curve has characteristic function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x^2}$ and the Taylor series around $x=0$ of that function is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{\pi}} \frac{x^{2n}}{n!}$$

Answer (score 4):

It is nothing more than what it sounds: you take a [ch.f](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Definition) and you consider its [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition).

The first thing that comes to mind is that the use of the Taylor expansion of a ch.f. is a crucial tool in one of the proofs of the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT).

If you want to read more on the subject I would recommend reading sections 3.3.3 and 3.4 from [Durrett's book](https://www.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf) ([ver.5](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/pte.html)).